# custom table type in stored procedure sap hana

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sapui5, hana

I'm new in the sap hana world. I'm trying to use stored procedures to update info. I want to send a custom table type with the field name, field value and row id.
I created this type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_field AS TABLE (
   ID INTEGER,
   FLD VARCHAR(100),
   VAL VARCHAR(100));
```

And I used it in this procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE "_SYS_BIC"."Match.procedures::updateAnag" (
    in tfield tt_field,
    out error tt_error
 ) 

 LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
 SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
 DEFAULT SCHEMA "_SYS_BIC"
 AS

BEGIN

     declare _id integer; 
     declare _field varchar(100);
     declare _value varchar(100);

     select ID, F_NAME, F_VALUE
     into _id, _field, _value
     from :tfield;

    IF(_field = '' OR _value = '') THEN
        error = SELECT 400 AS http_status_code,
                 'empty field' as error_message,
                  'All fields must be filled' as detail from dummy;
    ELSE

    IF (_field = 'name') THEN
        UPDATE "_SYS_BIC"."TEST_TABLE" 
        SET NAME = _value
        WHERE ID = _id;
    END IF;

    IF (_field = 'surname') THEN
        UPDATE "_SYS_BIC"."TEST_TABLE" 
        SET SURNAME = _value
        WHERE ID = _id;
    END IF;

    END IF;

END;
```

But when I try to activate the code, eclipse returns me this error:
'sap-ui-core.js:159 2016-07-19 17:45:47.751550 The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed400,Bad Request,Request contains properties that do not exist in entity 'anagType'. -'

Can someone help me to fix it or show me a better way to do this?

Comment: Ok, I get you want to be 'flexible' with your update procedure, but this is a clumsy way to do it. Make your info data block explicit and perform a direct UPDATE with a 1:1 mapping of the columns. Empty fields can either be manually checked or left to NOT NULL constraints on the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this post what interests me most is to understand why the procedure does not work with a custom table. This approach is an isolated case.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, from a SQLSCript code point of view, I'd say one problem here is that when you use the variables (like _value or _id) need to have the colon in front of them:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE "_SYS_BIC"."Match.procedures::updateAnag" (
    in tfield tt_field,
    out error tt_error
 ) 

 LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
 SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
 DEFAULT SCHEMA "_SYS_BIC"
 AS

BEGIN

     declare _id integer; 
     declare _field varchar(100);
     declare _value varchar(100);

     select ID, F_NAME, F_VALUE
     into _id, _field, _value
     from :tfield;

    IF(:_field = '' OR _:value = '') THEN
        error = SELECT 400 AS http_status_code,
                 'empty field' as error_message,
                  'All fields must be filled' as detail from dummy;
    ELSE

    IF (:_field = 'name') THEN
        UPDATE "_SYS_BIC"."TEST_TABLE" 
        SET NAME = :_value
        WHERE ID = :_id;
    END IF;

    IF (:_field = 'surname') THEN
        UPDATE "_SYS_BIC"."TEST_TABLE" 
        SET SURNAME = :_value
        WHERE ID = :_id;
    END IF;

    END IF;

END;
```

Another problem is that you don't initialize the table variable error in the second branch of the IF statement.

Not quite sure though, what all this has to do with your error message. You might want to call and test the procedure on its own first and then see why the connection to your xsjs page doesn't work properly.

Comment: I don't use xsjs page, I call this procedure from an .xsodata. I'll try this solution. Thanks!